# Load SVG with Picasso from URL

Tags: json, android-studio, picasso

I hope you can clarify my doubt, I want to upload an image in svg format from a URL but it does not show it on screen.

```
        Picasso.with(context).load(onlineDoctorsMs.get(position).getIconUrl()).resize(40, 40).into(holder.material_icon_specialty);
```

Comment: Did you find an appropriate way?